Continuity hypothesis in an exercise about the implicit function theorem
I want to solve the following exercise:
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set, and let $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose that $(x^2 + y^4) f(x, y) + f(x, y)^2 = 1$ for every $(x, y) \in U$. Show that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.
At first I thought this would be simply a direct application of the implicit function theorem to $g : U \times (0, 2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x, y, z) = (x^2 + y^4) z + z^2$, but I cannot see where to use the continuity hypothesis.
Could you help me, please?

I can at least illustrate why such an assumption is necessary. Suppose that $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ satisfies $f(x)^2-|x|=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Then without assuming $f$ is continuous, we get possible solutions like $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=-\sqrt{|x|}$ if $x\notin\Bbb Q$.

Where did $(0,2)$ come from?

It was a mistake from my part. The one at the right side made me imagine that I should take an interval around one at the right side, but not with 0, so that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$ is never 0. Now I see that I should take $U \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus {0})$.
